# Jump right at the point where the coordinates are 0 to find a constant minimum jump length to avoid all elements in a given array

Tags: java

Working through CodeSignal Arcade : https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-5/XC9Q2DhRRKQrfLhb5,

> You are given an array of integers representing coordinates of obstacles situated on a straight line.
> Assume that you are jumping from the point with coordinate 0 to the right. You are allowed only to make jumps of the same length represented by some integer.
>
> Find the minimal length of the jump enough to avoid all the obstacles.
>
> Example
>
> For inputArray = [5, 3, 6, 7, 9], the output should be
> solution(inputArray) = 4.
>
> Check out the image below for better understanding:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Lty.png
>
> Input/Output
>
> [execution time limit] 3 seconds (java)
>
> [input] array.integer inputArray
>
> Non-empty array of positive integers.
>
> Guaranteed constraints:
> 2 ≤ inputArray.length ≤ 1000,
> 1 ≤ inputArray[i] ≤ 1000.
>
> [output] integer
>
> The desired length.

This is my code:

```java
int solution(int[] a) {
    
    Arrays.sort(a);
    
    int ans = 0;
    
    for (int jump = 2; jump <= 1000; jump++) {
        
        int now = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        
        while(now<=a[a.length-1]){
            
            int next = now + jump;
            
            if(Arrays.binarySearch(a, next)<0){
                now = next;
            } else{
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            
        }
        
        if(flag) {
            ans = jump;
            break;
        }    
    }
    
    return ans;

}
```

What I trying to do in my code is :

1. sort array to get largest element
2. increase "jump" until it can avoid all the elements in input array

These are some given test cases:

> Input:
> inputArray: [5, 3, 6, 7, 9]
> Expected Output:
> 4
>
> Input:
> inputArray: [2, 3]
> Expected Output:
> 4
>
> Input:
> inputArray: [1, 4, 10, 6, 2]
> Expected Output:
> 7
>
> Input:
> inputArray: [1000, 999]
> Expected Output:
> 6
>
> Input:
> inputArray: [19, 32, 11, 23]
> Expected Output:
> 3
>
> Input:
> inputArray: [5, 8, 9, 13, 14]
> Expected Output:
> 6

I passed all the test cases, but I get tripped up on one of the hidden tests when submitted.
I can't find counterexample and error in my code.

Thanks ahead of time for the help. I'm still quite new to coding and appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

The code would fail for an array with all spots taken:
inputArray: [1, 2, 3, ..., 1000]

the expected solution is 1001

to fix it, you need to change the external for condition to `jump <= 1001`